# How to hack a computer on a different network?

Tags: kali-linux, information-gathering

I was wondering how I could "hack" a computer that is not on my network.

For example: open a meterpreter session on someone's computer who doesn't live within my proximity. I'm assuming I would need their IP address from their ISP? And maybe even a backdoor on the target computer?

Comment: Also, there's TONS of other information you may need to know. Like; what the OS is, what update it's on, what services are running, etc.

Comment: Two things are wrong with this. Too broad of a question and we are not _that_ type of community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IP addresses are IP addresses, so in theory, it doesn't matter where the target is.  But in real life there are a few things working against you:

Most PCs are behind a firewall which will prevent you from initiating a connection to the target.  You will have to figure out a way to get the target to initiate a connection to you (if you are also behind a firewall, this applies to you too).

The target is likely using Network Address Translation (NAT).  Their public IP (what you see) is not the same as their private IP (what their computer thinks it is).  Many devices can use the same public IP, so it;s very hard to know the real IP of the device you want to target.

Many ISPs do some level of malware detection, which may prevent you from installing a backdoor.  If they detect you, they will block your traffic. If your ISP detects you, they will cancel your service.

Finally, what you are asking about is illegal.  I don't know where you are, but in the US, it's a felony.  It's fine to talk theory, but we're not going to help you commit crimes.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not using is to commit crimes. I am just very interested in networking. Once again thank you for your help

Comment: That's OK.  As I said, learning about how networks work is perfectly fine.  If  your question is answered, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Do you know of any good books on learning about networking? The internet is filled with recommendations with everyone saying theirs is the best. Any ideas?

Comment: You might try Youtube.